# Which electromagnetic coil would have a stronger magnetic field, High amperage low voltage or low amperage high voltage?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetostatics

My apologies if the question is just too simplistic, I asked to ChatGPT and it said that the high amp low volt coil would be the strongest, I just want to confirm.

---

Assuming that both have the same size, same wattage and same number of turns, which coil would be stronger?

A coil with kilovolts, but milliamps/microamps or a coil with kiloamps, but millivolts/microvolts?

---

I ask this because of [this video](https://youtu.be/nCNkKrcnu7U) where a guy applied high amperage (around 100amps) to a copper coil and it contracted like a muscle. So I'm trying to understand more or less the role of amperage and voltage on coil strength.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your premises need to be straightened out a bit, as follows.

The magnetic field strength is proportional to the *product of amperes and coil turns*. To boost the field strength, you must either use fatter wire which has less resistance, so the current goes up- or you increase the applied voltage, which increases the current.

Now, note that if you try to increase field strength by adding more turns to the coil, the resistance goes up by just enough to cancel the effect of the extra turns and the field strength stays the same.

Similarly, if you try to increase the field strength by taking turns off the coil to reduce its resistance, the turns count goes down by the same factor as the current increase and the field strength stays the same.

Comment: To a first approximation, for the same power and the same quantity of copper, you get the same field.

Comment: @JohnDoty, and it's a good approximation. upping the wire diameter at constant turns requires adding copper.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big misunderstanding. Since what you call wattage is voltage times current you have always the product equal. But if you have a given coil you take the maximum voltage it allows and so get the maximum current.
But  ChatGPT  is right, the higher the current the stronger the magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

The force is proportional to the current, so higher current, higher force.  Nothing else matters.